# Why the code is comparison statement giving false;

Tags: javascript

```
function foo() {
   return
   {
      foo: 'bar'
   }
}

function bar() {
   return {
      foo: 'bar'
   }
}

typeof foo() === typeof bar(); //why this is false
```

I didnt get why typeof foo() === typeof bar() returing false

Answer (score 3):

Because of the line break after `return`, `foo()` is equivalent to

```
function foo() {
   return;
   //    ↑ note the semicolon
   {
      foo: 'bar'
   }
}
```

and is returning `undefined`.

On the other hand, `bar()` is returning an object.

Comment: i didn't understand if both function return `undefined` then `undefined === undefined` should be true??

Comment: @Girish: `bar()` is returning an object.